# Yii2 advanced template config

Tags: php, apache, nginx, yii2

Something wrong with my assets configuration, it looks to /usr/lib/cgi-bin/assets, which is wrong I guess. How to fix it?
Yii setup is initial.
[image]

Apache config:
[image]

Nginx config:
[image]

Comment: Have you got by any chance some `*.cgi` or `*.pl` files in the assets?

Answer (score 0):

I recently also had similar problem with missing folder `assets` (I don't know how that happened since I have installed Yii2 multiple times and that occurred just once). The difference was only different path to it.

What solved my issue is creation of that folder in specified path (which is `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` in your case and it should be an empty folder, no need to write anything in it).

After that, Yii2 system should generate all widgets' JavaScript and CSS files automatically (assuming your server allows that). Try to access the website and if you still have the same issue (which shouldn't be the case anymore?), check if there are any files/folders in your newly created `assets` folder.

Comment: I did this thing, just to test, and my pure application appeared. But js and css files didn't load because app was looking into assets folder under web catalog, which is empty  Meanwhile scripts were created in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/assets. Anyway I think it's completely wrong to use such approach, I have to bring this config to normal, to make whole thing work in application scope (under /var/www/app)